# How can i add different custom font to different target in iOS

Tags: swift, target, uifont

I am trying to add 3 different custom font to 3 different target how can i add that font. one storyboard have 3 labels which has bold, semi-bold, regular font weight with different size. i have added ttf font file in each target info.plist but how can i set font to each lable ???

Comment: You have to do this manually, something like creating a protocol named Themeable (which has a set font function). Then conform for each view controller | view had labels.

Comment: you mean if target == "this" { lable.font = .arialBoldFont(size: 17) } like this ?? @son

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, you mean 'different target' is different environments like dev, prod, stagging don't you?

Comment: no different target for different app fevers @son

Comment: If I read the question correctly it's not about flavors, targets at all? Because you've already added fonts for each target, the question is how to apply correct font to labels in storyboard, right?

Comment: yes correct @BojanBozovic

Answer (score 0):

1.check the font file is added to the projectworkspace
2.click the attributes inspector and you will find text click dropdown and choose attributed and you've to choose the font you added in your project and Finally again change text to plain